# get a resource path in MFC

Tags: html, mfc

I am trying to build HTML in my MFC application using class `CHtmlEditView`. 
So I want to add an image, currently I am using `<img align=\"baseline\" alt=\"\" src=\"C:\\cry.png\" border=\"0\" hspace=\"0\">` and its working all fine.

Now, I have to replace this `src=\"C:\\cry.png\"` local path. So I have added this to resources and  `<img align=\"baseline\" alt=\"\" src=\"\\res\\smiley.png\" border=\"0\" hspace=\"0\">` its not getting image path. I am not sure how to give a path a image from resources. I have seen `LoadBitmap`() and `LoadImage`() but do know how to get a relative path of resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target URL will be something like this:  `res://yourapplication.exe/agent.png`

Please note that you will need to import your image resources just like this:

- Go to **Resource View**
- right click and select Import context menu option
- select your image file

Please note that as the result you should have the following in your .rc file:

```
STARTPAGE.HTML          HTML                    "res\\startpag.htm"
AGENT.PNG               HTML                    "res\\agent.png"
```